# Postgres JOIN on multiple possible columns with OR statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables that I want to join together:

#### `contracts`:

| id | customer_id_1 | customer_id_2 | customer_id_3 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MAIN1 | TRAN1 | TRAN2 | 20201101 |
| 2 | MAIN2 |  |  | 20201001 |
| 3 | MAIN3 | TRAN5 |  | 20200901 |
| 4 | MAIN4 | TRAN7 | TRAN8 | 20200801 |

---

#### `customers`:

| id | customer_id | info | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MAIN1 | blah | 20200930 |
| 2 | TRAN2 | blah | 20200929 |
| 3 | TRAN5 | blah | 20200831 |
| 4 | TRAN7 | blah | 20200801 |

---

In my `contracts` table, each row represents a contract with a customer, who may have 1 or more different IDs they are referred to by in the `customers` table. In the `customers` table, I have info on customers (can be zero or multiple records on different dates for each customer). I want to perform a join from `contracts` onto `customers` such that I get the most recent info available on a customer at the time a contract is recorded, ignoring any potential customer info that may be available after the contract date. I am also not interested in contracts which have no info on the customers. The main problem here is that in `customers`, each customer record can reference any 1 of the 3 IDs that may exist.

I currently have the following query which performs the task as intended but the problem is that is *extremely* slow when run on data in the 50-100k rows range. If I remove the `OR` statements in the `INNER JOIN` and just join on the the first ID, the query performs in seconds as opposed to ~ half an hour.

```sql
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ON (ctr.id) 
  ctr.id, 
  ctr.customer_id_1, 
  ctr.date AS contract_date, 
  cst.info, 
  cst.date AS info_date
FROM 
  contracts ctr
  INNER JOIN customers cst ON (
    cst.customer_id = ctr.customer_id_1
    OR cst.customer_id = ctr.customer_id_2
    OR cst.customer_id = ctr.customer_id_3
  )
  AND ctr.date >= cst.date
ORDER BY
  ctr.id,
  cst.date DESC
```

#### Result:

| id | customer_id_1 | contract_date | info | info_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MAIN1 | 20201101 | blah | 20200930 |
| 3 | MAIN3 | 20200901 | blah | 20200831 |
| 4 | MAIN4 | 20200801 | blah | 20200801 |

It seems like `OR` statements in `JOIN`s aren't very common (I've barely found any examples online) and I presume this is because there must be a better way of doing this. So my question is, how can this be optimised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` often is a performance killer in SQL predicates.

One alternative unpivots before joining:

```
select distinct on (ctr.id) 
    ctr.id, 
    ctr.customer_id_1, 
    ctr.date as contract_date, 
    cst.info, 
    cst.date as info_date
from contracts ctr
cross join lateral (values 
    (ctr.customer_id_1), (ctr.customer_id_2), (ctr.customer_id_3)
) as ctx(customer_id)
inner join customers cst on cst.customer_id = ctx.customer_id and ctr.date >= cst.date
order by  ctr.id, cst.date desc
```

The use of this techniques pinpoints that your could vastly improve your data model: the relation between contracts and customers should be stored in a separate table, with each customer/contract tuple on a separate row - essentially, what the query does is virtually build that derived table in the lateral join.

Comment: Thanks @GMB! You're definitely right re the data model - unfortunately I don't have any control over that!